# scrapy not visiting url after #

Tags: scrapy

I am writing a **scraper** for a site. however weird thing is happening, it's not visiting the URL i supply to him. Rather it visits the base url of the website.

I searched on the internet and came to know that, scrapy would ingnore URL after #, I need to indentify the Ajax request being sent and mimic that.

However the problem is. the response of the Ajax request comes as json response. it's not a html content. Would someome please help me how to deal with it.

Following is the url

https://www.buildersshow.com/Search/Exhibitors.aspx#showID=11&state=160&tabname=name

Comment: it's not just Scrapy, the stuff after the ``#`` never goes to the server, it's always handled in the client. Handling a json response should be easier than scraping from HTML, you just need to do ``data = json.loads(response.body)`` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you investigate the AJAX requests that the page makes, identify the request you need to make and get your response, it should be JSON contained in the response body. To parse it and get your data of interest, use the `json` decoder/encoder module. Something like this:

```
import json

mydata = json.loads(response.body)
info = mydata['somekey']
subinfo = mydata['somekey']['subkey']
```

And so forth. Make sure to handle the json decoder the proper way, it would be best to read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) first.